# How can I add an external library to minigw compiler

Tags: c++, c, windows-10, mingw, ncurses

I've been trying for a couple days now to add an external library to my minigw installation on windows 10. I've downloaded the ncurses library and built it but I am having a hard time linking ncurses library to minigw. Any thoughts??

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Show us the error message you get.

Comment: You don't add a library to the compiler (typically, there are a few exceptions); however you can and will add a library to you project.  Assuming that minigw is really mingw you would use the same command form that you would use for gcc.  There are two option on the command line that you need to use: -L <path> were path is the path to where the library is and -l <name> where name is the name of the library to use without the leading 'lib' and the trailing '.so.x.y.x' so libncurses.so.6.3.0 just be ncurses.

Comment: It's easier to use msys2 to provide mingw and use its package management to download and install third party libraries for you instead of manually downloading and putting the binaries somewhere on your drive. [https://www.msys2.org/](https://www.msys2.org/)

Comment: MinGW is just the compiler. What exactly is your setup? Are you using MinGW from command line, MSYS2 shell or an IDE like Code::Blocks or Visual Studio Code or just from a Makefile or some other build tool like CMake? Basically you need the `-I` compiler to point to the include folder of your library (containing the C/C++ header files) and the `-L` linker flag to point to the folder containing library (`.a`) files. To run or debug the compiled result you may also need to add the folder containing the `.dll` file (in case of a shared library) to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.